# Avoid someone using my API out of my website

Tags: jquery, rest, cross-domain

I have been using an API from a website that I do not own. It has been working for 3 weeks, but now it is not. I've been using POSTMAN to check what was the problem, I just do not get a response. I tried putting the same headers as the browser does, and it's still not working. I must say that the URL is the same, and it works in the website.

So... what mechanism might been have used to avoid preventing me to use their API? I am really curious about it.

If it can help, the call to the API is like:

http://host.com/something/blabla?json.wrf=jQuery&q="blablabla"

I will be reporting here what I get from this.

Kind Regards,
McD0n3ld

Comment: Try setting the `referrer` and/or `origin` header to `http://host.com`

Comment: Thank you very much, it made the trick, but not in POSTMAN. With POSTMAN it did not work but did in a Java test program. Do you know why is that?